# Encrypted partitions with redundancy on ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, partition, raid1, disk-encryption

Hey I have to make a file system with an encrypted partition with on ubuntu server. something like

```
Unencrypted:
/ - 10 GB
/home - 10GB
/var - 5GB
--------------
Encrypted:
/opt - 50GB
```

This I can figure out in the setup, just partition as normal, setup /opt as a encrypted volume with dm-crypt. However im not sure how to mirror this entire drive, so that if either failed i could still boot. and how will that affect the encrypted partition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will be able to boot even if "/opt" will be unmountable, because it is not critical directory.

Comment: You mean `/opt`, not `/tmp` in the second paragraph, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is during the installation of the system.

Setup your two drives like this.

```
/dev/part1   ~200MB            fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/part2   EverythingElse    fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Setup two Software RAID1 volumes, One contain the first partition from both drives call that MD0, and the second containing the second partition and call that MD1.

Setup a filesystem on MD0 and the mount point for that will be /boot.  Setup MD1 to be dm-crypt volume.  Setup the dm-crypt volume for LVM volume group.  Create any partitions you want in your LVM volume group.  Everything in the LVM will be encrypted.

Comment: Alright, however since I want the OS unencrypted, save for the storage partition, would it be okay to do an MD0 raid of the 2 drives, LVM that into /, /boot, /home, and an encrypted volume, and then format that encrypted volume as /opt?

Mainly is there a problem having /boot in an LVM volume? Also, Ubuntu complains that it wants and encrypted swap space, so now would I need 
    MD0 raid of the 2 devices, 
    LVM that into /, 
                  /boot, 
                  /home, 
                  and 2 encrypted volumes
                  (ENC) /opt
                  (ENC) swap?

Comment: /boot cannot exist on LVM.  Swap should be encrypted, or people will just retrieve your encrypted stuff from the swap file.